# Libgdx: How to show HTML text in a label?

Tags: html, libgdx, jsoup, rtf

I have a string like this:

```
"noun<br> an expression of greeting <br>- every morning they exchanged polite hellos<br> <font color=dodgerblue> ••</font> Syn:  hullo,  hi,  howdy,  how-do-you-do<be>"
```

want to show it in a label as a rich text. for example Instead of `<br>` tags, text must go to the next line.

in Android we can do that with:

```
Html.fromHtml(myHtmlString)
```

but I don't know how to do it in libgdx.
I try to use Jsoup but it removes all tags and does not go to the next line for `<br>` tag for example.

```
Jsoup.parse(myHtmlString).text()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Jsoup.parse` returns a document containing many elements -of- strings. Not a single string so you are only seeing the first bit. You can assemble the complete string yourself by going through the elements or try

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(yourHtmlInput);
String htmlString = doc.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String htmlText = "<p>This is an <strong>Example</strong></p>";

//this will convert your HTML text into normal text
String normalText = Jsoup.parse(htmlText).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

in kotlin i use this code:

```
                var definition = "my html string"
                definition = definition.replace("<br>", "\n")
                definition = definition.replace("<[^>]*>".toRegex(), "")
```